# Catel framework - Lazy property

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I'm trying to create a lazy property with Catel framework. Is there a way to do it?

When I'm creating a property in ViewModel like this:

```
#region Photos property

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the Photos value.
/// </summary>
public FastObservableCollection<Photo> Photos
{
    get
    {
        var temp = GetValue<FastObservableCollection<Photo>>(PhotosProperty);
        if (temp == null)
            Photos = SelectedPatient.GetPhotos();
        return GetValue<FastObservableCollection<Photo>>(PhotosProperty);
    }
    set { SetValue(PhotosProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Photos property data.
/// </summary>
public static readonly PropertyData PhotosProperty = RegisterProperty("Photos", typeof (FastObservableCollection<Photo>));

#endregion
```

the `get` function is called even without binding, so my lazy property initializes while ViewModel is initializing.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Maybe there is an option to handle 'visibilitychanged' of a corresponding view from a ViewModel? It would also be an option (workaround)

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 way to implement "lazy properties", and that is by using the Lazy<> class. The reason for this is that for some mappings (such as view model to model, etc), Catel uses SetValue directly instead of the property wrapper (compare Catel properties with dependency properties).

Comment: Could you post a sample of that kind of property please?